# How to connect to sybase advantage db in java

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase, advantage-database-server

Firstly I would like to say that I'm new to *Java* programming and *Sybase*.

I have a problem with connection to *Sybase* database.

To establish the connection I have done:

1. Installation of jdbc driver for advantage db;
2. Set environment variable named CLASSPATH with url value to adsjdbc.jar (I installed jdbc drivers in c:\AdvJDBC so the path is c:\AdvJDBC\JDBC\adsjdbc.jar );

Then I'm tried to import drivers in my code:

```
public class SybaseCon {
      public static void main(String[] args){
         Class.forName("com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver");
}
```

And I'm getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver
```

I have searched for the solution in advantage *jdbc* driver help, but I found nothing that could resolve my problem.

Workaround:

- My Java version: jdk1.7.0_03
- Advantage file db: 11.0
- Advantage jdbc driver: 11.0

Comment: are you using your command prompt to execute?

Comment: Was all the required jars are in the  project folder ?

Comment: Paste some related codes more here..Make sure the jars are available in the path. This  occurs cause  of  [ClassNotFoundException](http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2012/03/jdbc-javalangclassnotfoundexception.html)

Comment: oh, it's something new:) do you talking about drivers jars (adsjdbc.jar) ? This drivers i have only in original installation directory (not in project folder).

Comment: ..yes very simple solution ,look into to the link for causes and recover it

Comment: @Strange, firstable I just want to import class so there is no more related code :) I still have a problem with it. I noticed that when i try to run my code in command prompt then i have a bit different error than in NetBeans. Error in cmd `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` (command: `java -cp c:\AdvJDBC\JDBC\adsjdbc.jar SybaseCon`). My bag with ideas is empty :)

Comment: Still are  you facing the  problem  ?Follow this [link](http://www.javaworkspace.com/connectdatabase/connectADS.do) it would help you to solve

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your CLASSPATH variable is actually set in the environment that you think it is.

Typically, in Windows, if you set the environment variable in the system settings, open command windows (and your open IDE) won't see the setting. You have to close and re-open them for it to take effect.

Try adding this to your code, just before the Class.forName line:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

It will show you the classpath that your application is actually using.

Second, you'll probably have a much easier time if you specify the classpath using java's preferred  path notation, which happens to align with unix/linux format - using forward slashes. Try using

```
java -cp /AdvJDBC/JDBC/adsjdbc.jar
```